# Why swagger Editor definitions type: file Report errors:Schema error

Tags: swagger-ui, swagger-editor

how can i use the "type:file" in definitions?
my yaml:

```
definitions:
  PageInfo:
    type: object
    properties:
      canonicalFile:
        type: file
```

the swagger editor Report errors:
Schema error at definitions.PageInfo.properties.canonicalFile.type
is not any of <#/definitions/simpleTypes>,[subschema 1]

and this swagger aip is auto created by swagger ui from my java cord.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

In OpenAPI/Swagger 2.0, the `file` type is only supported in form parameters and as the response date type.

In schema definitions, files are defined as `type: string` with `format: binary` (binary data) or `format: byte` (base64-encoded file contents).